# Why is CTRL + P not firing for my CDialog menu item?

Tags: visual-c++, hotkeys, cdialog, ccmenuitem

Sample menu:

```
IDR_MENU_PUBLISHERS_DATABASE MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "Database"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "Print\tCTRL + P",             ID_DATABASE_PRINT
    END
END
```

Handler:

```
void CPublishersDatabaseDlg::OnDatabasePrint()
{
    CFieldServiceGroupReportDlg dlgReport(this);

    dlgReport.DoModal();
}
```

Clicking the menu item handler works fine. But using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> does nothing. I tried creating am accelator table and using that approach by loading the table. No joy.

In the end I had to use `PreTranslateMessage` like this:

```
BOOL CPublishersDatabaseDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    BOOL    bNoDispatch = FALSE, bDealtWith = FALSE;

    if (IsCTRLpressed() &&
        pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN && pMsg->wParam == _TINT{ _T('P') })
    {
        OnDatabasePrint();
        // Eat it.
        bNoDispatch = TRUE;
        bDealtWith = TRUE;
    }

    if (!bDealtWith)
        bNoDispatch = __super::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);

    return bNoDispatch;
}
```

Why?

Comment: Maybe I just do things differently but adding the accelerator into the menu name in the resource file isn't the normal way to create an accelerator. You should create an `IDD_xxx ACCELERATORS` resource and add `"P", ID_DATABASE_PRINT, VIRTKEY, CONTROL` to that. The system will (should?) then add the 'Ctrl+P' text to the menu item.

Comment: The `IDD_xxx` will be the same as the ID for the `MENU` resource.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, that is what I tried too (with accelerator table). But we always use a tab and the key press to show on right. That is how boilerplate code is. I am wondering if control / p is hardwired to ID_FILE_PRINT or something deeper down.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah - a conflict with another command may be the problem. I don't think there's any "hardwire" to "Print" but maybe that's added by your mainframe's menu/accelerator resources?

Comment: How is the menu you've shown loaded/created? If you do it manually, I guess you'll also have to load the accelerators manually, alongside the process.

Comment: In all cases the menus are indicated in the resource IDE for the dialog. No manual code. If I use accelerator tables then I do load / destroy them when the dialog is created / destroyed. All other hotkeys work in the accelerator tables. None of my tables have CTRL + P yet. Bu t like I said, even when I did use it, nothing happened.

Comment: @AdrianMole Sorted. Forgot to add the required code to use `::TranslateAccelerator`.